# Smart-pointer template operator overload failing due to error C2244: "unable to match function definition to an existing declaration"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, templates, visual-c++

I have looked for dupes of this but forgive me if I missed a solution.

I have a smart pointer that has 2 comparison overloads, "==" and "<". Both of these operate on the underlying pointer only (inherited code before I am chastised). However on compilation I am getting a C2244 error for both. I will present the case for the equality operator only as the other is almost exactly the same:

> Error  4   error C2244: 'SmartRef::operator ==' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration   q:\projs\ha\src\SmartRef.cpp    114

The following code works fine in VC4.2 (I am porting to VC2008... courage).

**SmartRef.h**

```
#ifndef HA_INCL_REFERENCE
#define HA_INCL_REFERENCE 1

template <class TypeRefObj>
class SmartRef
{
public:

    //@cmember Default constructor
    inline SmartRef();

    //@cmember Constructor
    inline SmartRef( TypeRefObj * pThePointer );

    //@cmember Destructor
    inline ~SmartRef();

    //@cmember Copy constructor
    inline SmartRef( const NIEB_clReference< TypeRefObj > & roTheValue );

    //@cmember
    inline const SmartRef< TypeRefObj > & operator= ( const SmartRef< TypeRefObj > & roTheValue );

    //@cmember
    inline SmartRef< TypeRefObj > & operator= ( const SmartRef * pTheValue );

    //@cmember
    inline int operator== ( const SmartRef< TypeRefObj > & roTheValue ) const;

    //@cmember
    inline int operator< ( const SmartRef< TypeRefObj > & roTheValue ) const;

    //@cmember
    inline TypeRefObj & operator* () const;

    //@cmember
    inline TypeRefObj * operator-> () const;

private:
    //@cmember Reference pointer
    TypeRefObj * m_pRefPointer;
};
#include "SmartRef.cpp"
#endif //HA_INCL_REFERENCE
```

**SmartRef.cpp**

```
template <class TypeRefObj> 
inline int SmartRef< TypeRefObj >::operator== 
    ( SmartRef< TypeRefObj > & roTheValue ) const
{
    return m_pRefPointer == roTheValue.m_pRefPointer;
}
```

My first thought was that there was a problem because there was no comparison in the specialised classes, but then I realised that I am comparing pointers not objects. Then I thought maybe I need to be very explicit about that so I case both sides of the comparison to `void* but that made no difference. So now I am thinking that there is some reason that the definition is not valid in VC 2008. But I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong with the definition.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks,
Dennis.

**EDIT:**I'm embarrassed that it was so simple. I was missing a const from the definition. Thanks all, I don't know how I failed to spot it! Prize goes to first correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're lacking a `const` in the definition.

```
template <class TypeRefObj> 
inline int SmartRef< TypeRefObj >::operator== 
    ( const SmartRef< TypeRefObj > & roTheValue ) const
```

Also, you should define the member functions in the header - `#include` of a .cpp like you do doesn't do much for readability.

Comment: Thanks... this works. The choice to #include the .cpp was not mine. I'll get around to a code tidy once I get my exe out the other end. One step at a time. :)

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a broken SO record: use boost shared_ptr ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have omitted the const from the function in SmartPtr.cpp

```
template <class TypeRefObj> 
inline int SmartRef< TypeRefObj >::operator== ( const SmartRef< TypeRefObj > & roTheValue ) const
{
    return m_pRefPointer == roTheValue.m_pRefPointer;
}
```

Works

Answer (score 1):

Templates don't belong in a `.cpp` file, they belong in a header too, because the compiler needs to know the full code to instantiate templates of it. Then, you are missing the `const` in the definition of your `operator==`. Also, all comparision operators should return `bool`, not `int`.

Comment: BOOL is typedef'ed in this ancient code base as an int. The .cpp in #included in the .h and the .cpp is not part of the project... so that all works out fine. Thanks though.

Comment: @Dennis: Them better rename that to `.tpp`, it's a more common naming and isn't that confusing. Or even `SmartRef_Impl.h` would be good. `.cpp` is just misleading. And even though `BOOL` is typedef'd, there is the lowercase `bool`, which is its own distinct type.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers (ha ha... pun intended). The BOOL however will be remaining where it is until I have an opportunity to change it. Not arguing that that is not how it SHOULD be done. Just a matter of time (or lack thereof) at the minute.
:)